# Create Folders and Relocate Files Based on Partial Filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I have a series of photos in a folder with name format similar to this:

```
BA-ML-6256_Gocchup1.jpg
BA-ML-6256_Gocchup2.jpg
BA-ML-17302_Gocchup1.jpg
BA-ML-17302_Gocchup2.jpg
```

I want to create new folders like below that contain the files:

```
BA-ML-6256
BA-ML-17302
```

I tried using this script:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

but it created these 4 folders instead:

```
BA-ML-6256_Gocchup1
BA-ML-6256_Gocchup2
BA-ML-17302_Gocchup1
BA-ML-17302_Gocchup2
```

Please help me create a batch script that would make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the file names to derive the target folder name.

### Sample Batch File

The following batch file should do as you desire:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
  for /f "delims=_" %%j in (%%i) do (
    md %%j
    move "%%~i" "%%j"
  )
 )
)
```

This splits the file name at the "_" character to derive the target folder

### Example Output

I started with this folder layout:

```
  F:\projects\sx\batch>tree /f
  Folder PATH listing
  Volume serial number is 9C33-6BBD
  F:.
      create-test-data.cmd
      md-and-move.cmd
      BA-ML-6256_Gocchup1.jpg      
      BA-ML-6256_Gocchup2.jpg      
      BA-ML-17302_Gocchup1.jpg
      BA-ML-17302_Gocchup2.jpg

  No subfolders exist
```

Running the batch file gives this output:

```
  F:\projects\sx\batch>md-and-move.cmd
          1 file(s) moved.
  A subdirectory or file BA-ML-6256 already exists.
          1 file(s) moved.
          1 file(s) moved.
  A subdirectory or file BA-ML-17302 already exists.
          1 file(s) moved.
```

and results in this folder layout:

```
  F:\projects\sx\batch>tree /f
  Folder PATH listing
  Volume serial number is 9C33-6BBD
  F:.
  │   create-test-data.cmd
  │   md-and-move.cmd
  │
  ├───BA-ML-6256
  │       BA-ML-6256_Gocchup1.jpg
  │       BA-ML-6256_Gocchup2.jpg
  │
  └───BA-ML-17302
          BA-ML-17302_Gocchup1.jpg
          BA-ML-17302_Gocchup2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*.jpg"') DO (
 ECHO MD "%sourcedir%\%%b"
 ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b_%%c" "%sourcedir%\%%b"
)

GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Naturally, you could remove the `%sourcedir%\` throughout if you want to process the current directory.

The `dir` command lists the filenames only in the directory, and then only those that match `*_*.jpg`, that is *anything1*_*anything2*.jpg

The `for /f` assigns `anything1` to `%%b` and `anything2.jpg` to `%%c`, using the `_` as a delimiter (see `for /?` from the prompt, or thousands of items on SO for examples/documentation)

Then make the directory and move the file.

Simples!